# Event external display

Tags: display, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer, events

Does anyone know which event and event ID is triggered when an external monitor is connected and disconnected?
I can't seem to found an answer online.

What I would like to use it for is when the display is connected, the "closing the lid" action would do nothing. When disconnected, it goes back to the previous state: "sleep".

I found a solution using AutoHotKey but I'm a stubborn guy who wants to do this without any extra software.

I found that the WM_settingchange event is triggered but can't seem to find this in the logs at Event Viewer nor in Task Scheduler (where I would like to set this all up).
Triggering a script is fine but I just don't want any other software...

Comment: Windows does not trigger an event when an external monitor is connected or disconnected. This is handled by the display driver.

Comment: Got it! Thanks! Any way to capture this?

Comment: Not that I know of.